# Wordpress redirect remove

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Hello I am an new on WordPress. I  have a problem. My page is redirected automatically. There are many page and I cant found where is the redirect code.
when I came to my `company page` and select drop-down box for data filter then its showed data under the drop-down but then automatically redirect the page to `video page`. How to remove this redirection? 
I am found this code  `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');` bus as a new developer I cant understood this.
Thakns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be either a plugin called redirection or there is a line in the .haccess file that could be doing it or it could be in the page text. 1 of the 3